# Open the list title link in new window using jslink office 365

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, jslink

Below is the code i am using, it is not firing.

> Field Name is--> **Name(linked to item with edit menu)**

```
 (function () {

        //   Initialize the variables for overrides objects
        var overrideCtx = {};
        overrideCtx.Templates = {};



        //  Use BaseViewID and ListTemplateType to narrow focus/scope on 
        //  which web parts on the page are affected
        //overrideCtx.BaseViewID = 3;
       // overrideCtx.ListTemplateType = 170;

        /*
         * Using the Fields override leaves the rest of the rendering intact, but 
         * allows control over one or more specific fields in the existing view
         */


        overrideCtx.Templates.Fields = {
            "Title": { "View" : getLinkLocation }
        };



        /*
         * Register the template overrides.
         */
        SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides(overrideCtx);

    })();

    function getLinkLocation(ctx) {

    alert(ctx.CurrentItem.LinkLocation);

    alert("Before calling function");
        return '<a href=\"' + ctx.CurrentItem.LinkLocation + '\" target=\"_blank\">' + ctx.CurrentItem['LinkLocation.desc'] + '</a>';

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried it in my SPO and the modified code below works fine.

Here's your code and I modified the following codes

```
overrideCtx.Templates.Fields = {
        "LinkFilename": { "View" : getLinkLocation }
    };
```

and this line

```
return '<a href=\"' + ctx.displayFormUrl + '&ID=' + ctx.CurrentItem.ID + '\" target=\"_blank\">' + ctx.CurrentItem.FileLeafRef + '</a>';
```

Here's the full code

```
(function () {

    //   Initialize the variables for overrides objects
    var overrideCtx = {};
    overrideCtx.Templates = {};



    //  Use BaseViewID and ListTemplateType to narrow focus/scope on 
    //  which web parts on the page are affected
    //overrideCtx.BaseViewID = 3;
   // overrideCtx.ListTemplateType = 170;

    /*
     * Using the Fields override leaves the rest of the rendering intact, but 
     * allows control over one or more specific fields in the existing view
     */


    overrideCtx.Templates.Fields = {
        "LinkFilename": { "View" : getLinkLocation }
    };



    /*
     * Register the template overrides.
     */
    SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides(overrideCtx);

})();

function getLinkLocation(ctx) {

alert(ctx.CurrentItem.FileRef);

alert("Before calling function");
    return '<a href=\"' + ctx.displayFormUrl + '&ID=' + ctx.CurrentItem.ID + '\" target=\"_blank\">' + ctx.CurrentItem.FileLeafRef + '</a>';

}
```

Comment: Hi Aevntus, What if the field name is 'Name(linked to item with edit menu)'.?

Comment: Just use the internal name of the column. which is `LinkFilename`