# Use JSLink to Bold Title and open link in new window in SharePoint 2013

Tags: list-view, jslink, client-side-rendering

I used this solution to open my link in new window, it works great when alone.

[Open the list title link in new window using jslink office 365](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/191541/open-the-list-title-link-in-new-window-using-jslink-office-365)

But when I add to the code below, the title stays bold but the link stays overridden. How can I keep the inline look, with the bold title but keep the link active to open in a new window? All my combinations aren't working for me.

```
(function () {
    var overrideCtx;
    overrideCtx.Templates = {};
    overrideCtx.Templates.Item = CustomItem;
    overrideCtx.Templates.Header = "<b>Blog Title</b><br><br>";
    overrideCtx.Templates.Footer = "<br>";

    SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides(overrideCtx);
    }) ();

function CustomItem(ctx) {
    var ret = "<b>" + ctx.CurrentItem.Title + "</b>";
    var ret += "<br>Published Date: " + ctx.CurrentItem.Created;
    var ret += "<br>" + ctx.CurrentItem.Body;
    var ret += "<br># of Comments: " + ctx.CurrentItem.NumComments;
    var ret += "<hr>";
    return ret;
}
```

On the `CurrentItem.Title` tag, I added `LinkTitle` but it returned "undefined".

I also tried adding underneath the `.Header` tag:

```
overrideCtx.Templates.Fields = {
    "LinkTitle": { "View" : getLinkLocation }
};
```

and then the code below in conjunction with the `ctx.CurrentItem.Title` like:

```
var ret = "<b>" + '<a href=\"' + ctx.displayFormUrl + '&ID=' + ctx.CurrentItem.ID + '\" target=\"_blank\">' + ctx.CurrentItem.Title + '</a>' + "</b>";
```

but it wouldn't recognize it.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try `style="font-weight:bold;"` inside the `<a>` tag. It seems like css is overriding your changes and an `!important` clause could help that or adding the style in the tag directly

Comment: I added
overrideCtx.Templates.Fields = {"Link.Title":getLinkLocation}};

under the `.Header` tag

Comment: and then:

    function CustomItem(ctx) {
        var ret = "";
        var ret += "<a href=\"' + ctx.displayFormUrl + '&ID=' + ctx.CurrentItem.ID + '\" target=\"_blank\">' + ctx.CurrentItem.Title + '</a>';
    var ret += "<br>Published Date: " + ctx.CurrentItem.Created;
    var ret += "<br>" + ctx.CurrentItem.Body;
    var ret += "<br># of Comments: " + ctx.CurrentItem.NumComments;
    var ret += "<hr>";
    return ret;
}

Comment: I forgot to say I added the `style="font-weight:bold;"` and still Nothing works... I am stumped.

Comment: try the `style="font-weight:bold !important;"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, a few things I see going on here:

```
var overrideCtx;
```

needs to be

```
var overrideCtx = {};
```

Secondly, in your custom function, you only need to declare `var ret` on the first line.  On all the other lines you should remove `var`.

That all being said, the code below (which is I think what you were going for) works for me.  The link is bold, the link is active, and it opens in a new window.

```
(function () {
    var overrideCtx = {};
    overrideCtx.Templates = {};
    overrideCtx.Templates.Item = CustomItem;
    overrideCtx.Templates.Header = "<b>Blog Title</b><br><br>";
    overrideCtx.Templates.Footer = "<br>";

    SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides(overrideCtx);
})();

function CustomItem(ctx) {
    var ret = '<b><a href=\"' + ctx.displayFormUrl + '&ID=' + ctx.CurrentItem.ID + '\" target=\"_blank\">' + ctx.CurrentItem.Title + '</a></b>';
    ret += "<br>Published Date: " + ctx.CurrentItem.Created;
    ret += "<br>" + ctx.CurrentItem.Body;
    ret += "<br># of Comments: " + ctx.CurrentItem.NumComments;
    ret += "<hr>";
    return ret;
}
```

For what it's worth, you should remember that any fields you want to use in custom rendering need to be included in the view. `CurrentItem.LinkTitle` corresponds to "Title (linked to item)" or "Title (linked to item with edit menu)" when you are setting up your view.  My guess is your view only uses "Title", which is why `CurrentItem.LinkTitle` was undefined.